# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus with prerelease in dotnetcoreapp1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm compiling the prerelease version of [azure-service-bus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/) and attempting to run it in Visual Studio 2017 in an application which targets `netcoreapp1.1`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  <AssemblyName>Api</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm copying the compiled `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.*` files from `/bin/release/netstandard1.3/` into my project's `/lib` directory, then adding a Reference to it (using Browse).  My test code compiles fine, but at runtime I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=0.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at MyApp.DomainEvents.Tester.<Exec>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyApp\src\Profiles\DomainEvents\Tester.cs:line 43
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at ProfileManager.DomainEvents.Tester.Exec()
   at Api.Controllers.CurrentProfileController.<Get>d__3.MoveNext() in 
C:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyApp\src\Api\Controllers\CurrentProfileController.cs:line 39
```

Any idea why that is happening?

*Edit*: I verified that the .DLL was copied to the output directory.  I also see via Sysinternals Process Monitor that there are no attempts to access the file.

*Edit*: I don't get the error if I include the ServiceBus project directly in my Solution, then reference it via "Project" instead of "Browse"....  Not sure why...

Comment: There's a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.servicebus

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed the prerelease. :(

Comment: Anything else that at runtime copies an older version and overrides the one that you bring in manually? I'd try on an empty/new project to see if things are working.